# Private C# property during TypeScript callback not in .data property

Tags: c#, angularjs, callback, typescript, promise

So, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here but for some reason the callback function in TypeScript that i have doesn't have anything but _proto in the response's .data property whenever i set private properties in C# and new up an object that is filled with constructed properties. However, if the properties are public and i don't use a constructor then i can see the response's .data property is filled like i would expect it to be. Here is an example of what works:

```
public class ThisWorks{
   public string MyProperty{get;set;}
  }
```

Inside application layer:

```
ThisWorks example = new ThisWorks();
example.MyProperty = myReflectedProperty;
return example;
```

However, this does not work:

```
 public class ThisDoesNotWork{
   private string MyPrivateProperty {get;set;}
      public ThisDoesNotWork(string myPrivateProperty){
            MyPrivateProperty = myPrivateProperty;
             }
        }
```

What's causing this to happen? My TypeScript service has not changed but for some reason the data isn't coming across from the service call...Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Also, Serialization is NOT constructive for this thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control access to a property, you can normally do this very will without a method in C#...

It *appears* that you want the ability to set the property, but not read it. The following is an example of a public write-only property, which you can read and write in private context.

This appears as a property to callers, rather than a method.

```
public class Example
{
    private string _exampleProperty;
    public string ExampleProperty
    {
        set { _exampleProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, i think you misunderstood what i was saying.  I know that a public property will work for me.  However, it's the private property that will not.  Also, after attempting to follow this example i still did not see anything but _proto in my returned .data property of my response in TypeScript.  This is NOT a C# only issue, it's an issue with getting data to commit across languages within a Visual Studio project.  Does that help?